# Detecting Doze State

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to detect when a device enters Doze/Standby? I haven't been able to find anything in the Android documentation about a possible Broadcast Receiver or Listener that I could enable or create in order to receive notifications of these transitions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe the `Intent` you're looking for is [`ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED). From the documentation:

> Intent that is broadcast when the state of isDeviceIdleMode() changes. This broadcast is only sent to registered receivers.

The documentation for [`isDeviceIdlemode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isDeviceIdleMode()) is as follows:

> Returns true if the device is currently in idle mode. This happens when a device has been sitting unused and unmoving for a sufficiently long period of time, so that it decides to go into a lower power-use state. This may involve things like turning off network access to apps. You can monitor for changes to this state with `ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED`.
>
> **Returns**
>
> Returns true if currently in active device idle mode, else false. This is when idle mode restrictions are being actively applied; it will return false if the device is in a long-term idle mode but currently running a maintenance window where restrictions have been lifted.

Comment: interesting? is it expected to indicate the right value in doze mode as well? given that any cpu work actually stops [to even run this method], from what I know.

Comment: looks like doze and idle are not the same. as confusing as that can be

Comment: it is confusing indeed. so is this intent going to be fired before the phone enters doze mode?

Comment: Per docs https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#testing_doze_and_app_standby the command to enter doze mode is `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle` so I assume that `idle` mode is the same as `doze` mode.

Comment: my brain exploded :) isDeviceIdlemode = false is actually the period where I should do things . It is when it resumes from Doze to process messages ?