# Is it possible to know when device enters into Doze (STATE_IDLE) mode?

Tags: android, performance

I'd like to ask whether it is possible to receive a notification from the OS when the device is just about to enter into [Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) mode (STATE_IDLE).

Comment: please go through to this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143559/5308778](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143559/5308778)